# react-native-mapbox-gl: CircleLayer interferes with tap on the markers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl

**Problem statement:**

I am using MapBox `8.2.0-beta2`. I have four layers:

1. Type 1 marker
2. Type 2 marker
3. Vicinity circle around the selected marker
4. Selected marker (used to highlight a marker with red color when user taps on a marker)

I use `guid` to find out which marker is selected by the user. And `type` to color-render the two types of marker. Note that I have added the layers in the **correct order**.
Bellow you can see a minimal example:

```js
        <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
            id="shapetest"
            shape={featureCollection}
            onPress={onPressMarker}>
          <MapboxGL.CircleLayer
              id="circle"
              style={layerStyles.circle}
              minZoomLevel={15}
              filter={['==', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]}
          />
          <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
              minZoomLevel={14}
              id="type1"
              style={layerStyles.type1}
              filter={[['==', 'type', "1"], ['!=', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]]}
          />
          <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
              id="type2"
              style={layerStyles.type2}
              minZoomLevel={14}
              filter={[['==', 'type', "2"], ['!=', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]]}
          />
          <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
              minZoomLevel={14}
              id="symbolsSelected"
              style={layerStyles.iconSelected}
              filter={['==', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]}
          />
        </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>

const layerStyles = {
  circle: {
    circleRadius: [
      'interpolate',
      ['linear'],
      ['zoom'],
      15, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 1.5],
      16, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 2],
      17, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 3],
      18, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 5],
      19, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 10],
      20, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 15],
      21, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 30],
      22, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 55],
    ]
  },
  type2: {
    iconImage: pin2,
    iconSize: 0.08,
    iconAllowOverlap: true,
    iconAnchor: 'bottom',
  },
  type1: {
    iconImage: pin1,
    iconSize: 0.08,
    iconAllowOverlap: true,
    iconAnchor: 'bottom',
  },
  iconSelected: {
    iconImage: pin3,
    iconSize: 0.08,
    iconAllowOverlap: true,
    iconAnchor: 'bottom',
  },
}
```

**Current behavior:**
When a few markers are located near each other  AND the `CircleLayer` covers them, some of the markers cannot be selected. Instead, I can see that MapBox returns the same marker that was selected previously. When markers are far apart from each other, everything works fine.

**Desired behavior:**
When the markers are pressed by the user, `CircleLayer` should not interfere with the markers, regardless of the markers' distance to each other, and the user should be able to select any marker.

Below you can see the current scenario:

- light green: type 1 marker
- blue: type 2 marker
- red: selected marker
- green circle: `CircleLayer`

[image: example]

Considering the current scenario, when you tap on the **light green** marker that is covered by the `CircleLayer`, I can see that always the blue marker is selected (I can verify this in the console), and you can never select the **light green** marker (undesired behavior).

Comment: Can you please share more code? 'guid' was pulled from onPressMarker? I don't see any guid available in onPress from MapboxGL.ShapeSource when i print out the value on my own machine

Answer (score 0):

Adding another ShapeSource layer without the onPress method solves the problem:

```
   <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
        id="shapetest"
        shape={featureCollection}>
        <MapboxGL.CircleLayer
            id="circle"
            style={layerStyles.circle}
            minZoomLevel={15}
            filter={['==', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]}
        />
    </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
    <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
        id="shapetest"
        shape={featureCollection}
        onPress={onPressMarker}>
        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
            minZoomLevel={14}
            id="type1"
            style={layerStyles.type1}
            filter={[['==', 'type', "1"], ['!=', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]]}
        />
        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
            id="type2"
            style={layerStyles.type2}
            minZoomLevel={14}
            filter={[['==', 'type', "2"], ['!=', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]]}
        />
        <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
            minZoomLevel={14}
            id="symbolsSelected"
            style={layerStyles.iconSelected}
            filter={['==', 'guid', selectedNoteGuid]}
        />
    </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
    
    const layerStyles = {
      circle: {
        circleRadius: [
          'interpolate',
          ['linear'],
          ['zoom'],
          15, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 1.5],
          16, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 2],
          17, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 3],
          18, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 5],
          19, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 10],
          20, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 15],
          21, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 30],
          22, ['*', ['get', 'geoAccuracy'], 55],
        ]
      },
      type2: {
        iconImage: pin2,
        iconSize: 0.08,
        iconAllowOverlap: true,
        iconAnchor: 'bottom',
      },
      type1: {
        iconImage: pin1,
        iconSize: 0.08,
        iconAllowOverlap: true,
        iconAnchor: 'bottom',
      },
      iconSelected: {
        iconImage: pin3,
        iconSize: 0.08,
        iconAllowOverlap: true,
        iconAnchor: 'bottom',
      },
    }
```